# Error on when class is called on custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am trying to call my class from a custom button i wrote javascript on the button click but i am getting this error [image]

my code on custom button for execution :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}
sforce.apex.execute("HttpControllerCPFMirror","callApproval",{});
alert("done");
```

my class

```
public class HttpControllerCPFMirror {
  public void doRequest() {
  }
}
```

please guide me what is the issue i am getting.

Comment: I have also used the code as sforce.apex.execute("CpfJobGetResponse","OpportunityParse",{id:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); but still getting this error

Comment: Can you post an outline of the class HttpControllerCPFMirror  i.e. its class declaration and the callApproval method signature?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

As this call is actually invoking the class via a web service you need this signature:

```
global class HttpControllerCPFMirror {
    webservice static void callApproval() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the method has to be static i.e. all state must be passed into the call from the page.

Here is a Force.com Cookbook posting [Creating a Button with Apex](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-button-with-apex) that provides an example.

Comment: It works but when i try to pass parameter with the sforce.apex.execute("HttpControllerCPFMirror","callApproval",{id:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); i am getting the same error that problem onclick javascript button link encountered. Any idea over this issue. I am getting the the parameter as id OppId = apexpages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().get('id');

Comment: Your callApproval method must have a corresponding argument defined - see the Cookbook example. `ApexPages.currentPage()` is not relevant to this type of call.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/apex.js")}
try {
var oppids = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
var r = confirm("Do you want to update Opportunity?");
if(r == true)
{
  sforce.apex.execute("HttpControllerCPFMirror","callApproval",{OppId:oppids });
  window.location.reload();
  }
 } 
 catch(e) 
 { 
 }
```

my class :

```
global class HttpControllerCPFMirror {
webservice static void callApproval(id oppid) {

}
}
```